# Xcode build failed with: /bin/sh: /Users/.../ios/App/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-App/Pods-App-frameworks.sh: Operation not permitted

Tags: ios, xcode, capacitor

I've tried almost everything:

1. Executable permission:

   chmod +x Pods/Target\ Support\ Files/Pods-App/Pods-App-frameworks.sh
2. Clean build folder
3. Reinstall pods

   pod deintegrate && pod install

If set
ENABLE_USER_SCRIPT_SANDBOXING = NO
build succeeded!

I use Xcode 15 on macOS Sonoma.
The problem started after Sonoma update.
Thanks in advance.